# Having trouble passing data to controller in Asp.Net Core MVC using tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to learn how to pass data into an `HttpPost` function in Asp.Net Core MVC using tag helpers.

Here is my Model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CustomerInput" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblId">
                Id
            </label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Id" type="text" class="form-control" id="lblId" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lblName">
                Name
            </label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="lblId" disabled>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Exists" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="chkExists">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="chkExists">
                    Exists
                </label>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="btnNext" value="Next" class="btn btn-secondary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CustomerInput()
    {
        var model = new PersonModel { Id = 1, Name = "Homer Simpson", Exists = false };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CustomerInput(PersonModel model)
    {
        return View("CustomerOutput", model);
    }
```

When I attempt to submit the form and pass the model to my `HttpPost` function, only the `Exists` value passes successfully. `Id` is always 0 and `Name` is always null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove disabled and add readonly...inside your inputs

Comment: That did it! @GHDevOps post an answer to this question and I will mark it.

Comment: No, this shouldn't be answered.  It's better to mark this as a duplicate and close it.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled inputs won't post back to the controller. Use readonly:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Id" type="text" class="form-control" id="lblId" readonly>
```

See devlin carnate's post for clarity

It's also good practice to use unique identifiers for your input id's!

Comment: It's better to allow this question to get closed as a duplicate rather than answer a question that has been asked & answered many other times, FYI